# After linking urls&views "hello world" is not visible in django

Tags: python, django, django-views, http-status-code-404

i have just now started learning the django basics ,but i have been keeping on facing a problem with the urls & views. i do not get the "Hello world" after i reload or even try adding myapp name in the url

wrote this code for the project url

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('calc.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

wrote this for myapp urls

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
]
```

wrote this for the views

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

# Create your views here.
def home(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello world");
```

what is the mistake i am doing?

link: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/calc`

Comment: Please stop writing in all CAPS

Answer (score 0):

You are not setting the correct URL. Also have you added your in installed apps ?
if yes then visit: `http://127.0.0.1:8000`

or add `calc` in your url to use `http://127.0.0.1:8000/calc`

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('calc', views.home, name='home'),
]
```

Comment: but after adding to the installed app again i face the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Is your myapp urls file inside a folder called calc? If it isn't then try doing something like this:

Change `include('calc.urls')` to `include('\the folder name in which myapp urls is in\.urls')`

Then use the `http://127.0.0.1:8000` and it should work.